# VBA: Run-Time Automation Error - "Code execution has been interrupted"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to write a program to loop through a directory of excel files and copy a range into a "Master Workbook". When I run the program I am prompted with "Code execution has been interrupted". If I select continue the code will successfully run but then a "run-time error '-2147221080' Automation error" appears.

The line that causes the error is:

```
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Project Log")
```

My question is, why is this line causing the error and or is there a way to bypass the error prompt so that my code will successfully run?

```
 Sub FileCompiler()
 Dim folderPath As String
 Dim Filename As String
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim Masterwb As Workbook
 Dim ws as Worksheet
'set workbook in which data will be copied to
Set Masterwb = ActiveWorkbook

'declare path
'folderPath = "C:MyPath\"

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"

'compile directory data to master spreadsheet
Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls*")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Project Log")
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "C"), ws.Cells(2, "C")).Copy
    Masterwb.Worksheets("Staging").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(7, "A"), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).Copy
    Masterwb.Worksheets("Staging").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    wb.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You'd see that error if there was no sheet with that name.  Does that sheet exist in every workbook?  FYI you have two `ws.Range(...).Copy` in a row there - the first line will have no effect.  Also you're not altering the opened workbooks, so you can use `wb.Close False`

Comment: @TimWilliams Does that error normally come up with a missing sheet? If I try accessing a sheet that doesn't exist, I generally get a `Subscript Out of Range Error 9` type error. This reported error code seems to popup when trying to access a sheet in an unopened workbook. But his code doesn't throw an error when opening the workbook (so it should be open). As an example, if you `Set wb = Workbooks.Open... wb.Close Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")` you'd get the referenced error.

Comment: might be an idea to also add `Dim ws as Worksheet`

Comment: When it breaks on the error is the workbook open, and does it have a sheet with that name?  It's easy to check...

Comment: ^^^^ Declare your ws as a worksheet.  It might have to be active to set it.  You don't have to worry about your master you already set it when active.

Comment: @TimWilliams I just updated my code. I have confirmed that the workbook I am opening has a sheet named "Project Log"

Comment: Look at the code below, the important steps are setting your current workbook, getting a filename, opening that workbook and then setting it.  Now you have two workbook references and likely at least 2 worksheet references.  You can set the second workbook after opening it, it wont do this right if you don't open it first IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Dim Finfo As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Long
    Dim Title As String
    Dim CopyBook As Workbook
    Dim CopySheet As Worksheet
    Dim ForecastFileName As Variant 
    Dim MasterSheet AS Worksheet

Set MasterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yoursheetname")
'now you can always use master sheet after you set copybook 

  'Set up file filter
    Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
    'Set filter index to Excel Files by default in case more are added
    FilterIndex = 1
    ' set Caption for dialogue box
    Title = "Hey there!, select a file"

    'get the Forecast Filename
    ForecastFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, FilterIndex, Title)

'Change this according to what you need for workbook and worksheet names
Workbooks.Open (ForecastFileName)
Set CopyBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set CopySheet = CopyBook.Worksheets(1)

'Do your code, remember to close

CopyBook.Close savechanges:=False 'Not needed now
```

You might want to check for the ForecastFileName being False, that is when the users x's out, you will also want to do a little validation the wb sheet is in the right format by checking column headers ect or you will wind up crashing.