# Macro to copy certain cells from one workbook to another and append data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro to copy certain cells from one workbook to another. I need to append the new data to data that has already been transferred. I am trying to modify this code to do so, but am not having success:

```
Sub Consolidate()
'Author:     Jerry Beaucaire'
'Date:       9/15/2009     (2007 compatible)  (updated 4/29/2011)
'Summary:    Merge files in a specific folder into one master sheet (stacked)
'            Moves imported files into another folder
' Edited/altered by Jay Chase 6/9/2017

Dim fName As String, fPath As String, fPathDone As String
Dim LR As Long, NR As Long
Dim wbData As Workbook, wsMaster As Worksheet

'Setup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro execution
    Application.EnableEvents = False    'turn off other macros for now
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'turn off system messages for now

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BM Condition")    'sheet report is built into

With wsMaster
    If MsgBox("Clear the old data first?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Clear
        NR = 2
    Else
        NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'appends data to existing data
    End If

'Path and filename (edit this section to suit)
    fPath = "C:\Users\jchase.BRYCEWORLD\Desktop\Test\"            'remember final \ in this string"
    fPathDone = fPath & "Imported\"     'remember final \ in this string
    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir fPathDone                 'creates the completed folder if missing
    On Error GoTo 0
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*New BM Analysis 3.xls")        'listing of desired files, edit filter as desired

'Import a sheet from found files
    Do While Len(fName) > 0
        If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then              'don't reopen this file accidentally
            Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)  'Open file

        'This is the section to customize, replace with your own action code as needed
            LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Find last row
            Range("P14:S" & LR).EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & NR)
            wbData.Close False                                'close file
            NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1  'Next row
            Name fPath & fName As fPathDone & fName           'move file to IMPORTED folder
        End If
        fName = Dir                                       'ready next filename
    Loop
End With

ErrorExit:    'Cleanup
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True         'turn system alerts back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True          'turn other macros back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        'refreshes the screen
End Sub
```

I have little experience with VBA. Any help with how or why or why not I can do this is appreciated. I am still experimenting; if I have any breakthroughs I will update.

EDIT: so i have realized this code has to be called from the workbook i want to write to, but i need to call it from the workbook i am reading from. Is there a way to modify this script to do so?

Comment: you will have to be sure this path is right:  fPath = "C:\Users\jchase.BRYCEWORLD\Desktop\Test\"            'remember final \ in this string"

Comment: you will have to be sure this filename is right:  fName = Dir(fPath & "*New BM Analysis 3.xls")

Comment: This is going to kick back out to the calling code to handle the error, make sure you have it handled in the calling code that you have not posted:  On Error GoTo 0

Comment: you will have to be sure the workbook your code is in has this worksheet and worksheet name: Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BM Condition")    'sheet report is built into

Comment: What errors are you getting?  More info needed

Comment: i have an 'error 52' in this line:  fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xlsm*")        'listing of desired files, edit filter as desired
i am realizing i need to call this in the sheet i want to write to though, and i need to call it in the sheet im reading and have it then write to the master sheet

Comment: that line is going after a very specific filename.  your fpath declared above must be correct and the, ".xlsm" is looking for a file with no name, that wont do, you need to provide the file name "myProject.xlsm" for instance.  If you want code to open the file search option and select the file and the path as well instead of hard coding it would like like this answer in the get and open file section.

Comment: Example Answer that opens the file browser to get the path and the name here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177526/8716187